# Is it possible to compile Go programs to LLVM IR?

Tags: go

I found this project: 
https://github.com/go-llvm/llgo.
But the last commit was almost 4 years ago and they mention:

> This project has moved to llvm.org. Any contributions or bug reports should be sent there. Please refer to the llgo readme for more information

So is it unusable for today's programs?

Another project is:
https://go.googlesource.com/gollvm.
But according to their website, it is still in development. But is it stable enough to use it now and will it be developed further?

> Gollvm is currently in development -- releases are not yet available for download. Instructions for building gollvm follow.

Are there any other projects or ways to compile Go to LLVM IR, or is it not possible yet?

Comment: llgo was not used to compile go to LLVM. It was a tool **written in go** to use LLVM.

Answer (score 2):

[GOLLVM](https://go.googlesource.com/gollvm) is still being maintained, It is stable and its latest commit was in August. Therefore the project is not dead.

However, it only targets x64 Linux right now. So your application would not run on macOS or Windows.